# how to apply bold and uppercase in the textview using java mode ( android )

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

I would like to apply bold and uppercase style in a TextView using java mode. However, bold style is not working with uppercase text, because the element `<b>` not work when is `<B>`.

Ex:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("message `<b>`example`</b>`");

String text = textview.getText().toString();
textview.setText(text.toUpperCase());
```

Returns:

MESSAGE EXAMPLE;

Expected:

MESSAGE **EXAMPLE**;

Comment: What hapens when you set the [android:textAllCaps="true"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textAllCaps) in the layout file and then set the text of the TextView programatically ?

Comment: I tried but this way not work too, display the uppercase text but without bold text.

Answer (score 1):

Now I can to do it:

Example:

TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

String text = "test `<b>`example`</b>`";

textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text.toUpperCase()));

Return TEST **EXAMPLE**

Answer (score 0):

Simply do a `replace("<B>", "<b>")` and `replace("</B>", "</b>")` on your `text.toUpperCase()` before using it in `setText()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have to be able to decide which part of the text you want to be bold you could just turn arround the order.

In this case, "example".toUpperCase() and wrap it on  afterwards. so the `<b>` tag wont be upper case

```
String examplePart = "example";
String messagePart = "message";

String finalConstruct = messagePart + "<b>" + examplePart.toUpperCase() + "</b>"

textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(finalConstruct));
```

this should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

First define a string resource as:

```
<string name="formatted_text">%1$s &lt;b>%2$d&lt;/b></string>
```

Then in your activity; just do

```
String text1 = "message";
String text2 = "example";
String textFormat = getResources().getString(R.string.formatted_text);
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format(textFormat, text1, text2.toUpperCase()));
);
```

Using resources is not necessary but I prefer using it that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
**string.xml**
<string name="example_message">example &lt;b>message&lt;/b></string>

**Activity**
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(((getString(R.string.example_message).toUpperCase()).replace("<B>","<b>")).replace("</B>","</b>")));
```